# Issues with editing the Your Communities section

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

I have collected some issues with editing the Your Communities section.

**Issue with displaying only one entry**

When i select only one entry in the `Your Communities` per editing this section, the styling of the displayed entry gets lost.

Doing a page reload, will fix it and the entry is displayed correctly. So i think the issue is only directly after editing the entries.

[image]

**Removing all entries issue**

Another problem is that it is not possible to remove all entries from `Your Communities`. This will reset it to the default list. I´m not sure if any user will remove all entries from this section, but the behavior seems to be incorrect.

**Dragging of entries issue**

Dragging entries to the right will scroll the the PopUp.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Issue with displaying only one entry

This was fixed a few days back.

> Removing all entries issue

This is firmly [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign): [Removing all "my communities" causing the list to reset](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224093/removing-all-my-communities-causing-the-list-to-reset).

> Dragging of entries issue

And this will be fixed in the next build.

Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution to the last point is a simple `axis: "y"` in the config options for jQuery UI sortable.